# Pointers and function arguments

Tags: c

The code snippet below gives the output 11 11 undefined value. But why am I getting the undefined value when the same statement is executed second time ? Is that anything to do with the scope of the function?

```
   void foo(int **const p)
        {
            int j = 11;
            *p = &j;
            printf("%d ", **p);
        }

    int main()
        {
            int i = 10;
            int *p = &i;
            foo(&p);
            printf("%d ", *p);
            printf("%d ", *p);
        return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pointing to an item which has been already deallocated as soon as `foo` function returns. This is an error, then the undefined behaviour happens.

After a variable goes out of scope, it's not automatically overwritten, its value simply remains there until some other instruction uses that memory location to store another value. In the example, the execution of the first printf overwrites the memory location pointed by p, that's why when you read it a second time, you see that its value has changed.

You could fix it as follows:

```
void foo(int **const p)
{
    int *j = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
    free(p)
    return 0;
 }
```

It's not beautiful but for educational purposes it can be good.

Answer (score 5):

When `foo()` exits, `*p` points to a variable that is no longer in existence. Therefore you are invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is something that I still can't understand, why it works for the first time after function execution, and fails on following attempts. I would expect it to fail also for the first printf in main

Comment: @DavidBo That is the point - **anything** can happen. There are no rules as to how a program behaves once undefined behaviour has been invoked. It will depend on your implementation. The main rule is not to invoke UB at all.

Comment: @DavidBo it depends on how the code is compiled. After a variable goes out of scope, it's not automatically overwritten, its value simply remains there until some other instruction uses that memory location to store another value. In the example, the execution of the first printf overwrites the memory location pointed by p, that's why when you read it a second time, you see that its value has changed.