# why the second printf prints garbage value

Tags: c, garbage

this is the source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *fun();

int main()
{  
    int *j;
    j=fun();
    printf("%d\n",*j);
    printf("%d\n",*j);
    return 0;
}

int *fun()
{
    int k=35;
    return &k;
}
```

output-

```
35
1637778
```

the first printf() prints 35 which is the value of k but

In the main() the second printf prints a garbage value rather than printing 35.why?

Comment: answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880084/pointers-and-function-arguments/20880143#20880143

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is the return from `fun` is returning the address of a local variable.  That address becomes invalid the moment the function returns.  You are simply getting lucky on the first call to `printf`.

Even though the local is technically destroyed when `fun` returns the C runtime does nothing to actively destroy it.  Hence your first use of `*j` is *working* because the memory for the local hasn't been written over yet.  The implementation of `printf` though is likely over writing this simply by using its own locals in the method.  Hence in the second use of `*j` you're referring to whatever local `printf` used and not `k`.

In order to make this work you need to return an address that points to a value that lives longer than `fun`.  Typically in C this is achieved with `malloc`

```
int *fun() {
  int* pValue = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *pValue = 23;
  return pValue;
}
```

Because the return of `malloc` lives until you call `free` this will be valid across multiple uses of `printf`.  The one catch is the calling function now has to tell the program when it is done with the retun of `fun`.  To do this call `free` after the second call to `printf`

```
j=fun();
printf("%d\n",*j);
printf("%d\n",*j);
free(j);
```

Comment: but stack follow lifo ,so k should be removed from the stack first,so how first printf() gives correct output

Comment: @user3162531 in general C doesn't actually remove the stack values when returning from a function.  It just adjusts the stack pointer to point back to the calling function.  Until the local is explicitly over written by another piece of code the value will generally speaking still be accessible.  Never depend on this behavior though, it's just an artifact of most implementations

Comment: but why the second printf() over write the k in stack? why not the first printf()?

Comment: you said that stack is not cleared until the local is explicitly over written by another piece of code ..
so in my case why second printf() overwrite the local k why not the first printf()

Comment: @user3162531 the first printf is over writing the stack.  The expression `*j` is evaluated before `printf` is run.  Hence the address of the dead local is read, then printf runs and overwrites the value

Comment: this means in every     printf() the expression inside is evaluated first

Comment: @user3162531 every expression that is an argument to `printf` is evaluated before anything in the function is executed.

Comment: is this the case with every function

Comment: @user3162531 yes that is how function execution works for any function.  The argument expressions are evaluated, then control moves the the called function

Comment: @user3162531 Additionally be aware that, depending on the position of `*j` in the parameter list, it might be overwritten while pushing the arguments for the first `printf()` as well. So never rely on UB.

Answer (score 3):

Program invokes **undefined behavior**. You can't return a pointer to an automatic local variable. The variable no longer exist once `fun` returns. In this case the result you get, may be expected or unexpected.
**Never return a pointer to an automatic local variable**

Answer (score 2):

You are returning local value it is stored in stack. When you move out of function it gets erased. You getting `undefined behaviour`.

In your case `stack` not changed after function returning, so first time you getting correct value. This is not same in all time.

Answer (score 1):

Both are wrong, since you print a value that no longer exists: the memory to store `int k` in the function is ok only while the function is executing; you can't return a reference (pointer) to it, since it will no longer reference anything meaningful.

The following, instead, would work:

```
int *fun()
{
  static int k=35;

  return &k;
}
```

The static keyword "says" that the memory must "survive" even if the function is not running, thus the pointer you return will be valid.

Answer (score 1):

As others already told, your program invokes undefined behavior.

That means, anything can happen where the behaviour is not defined.

In your case, the following happens: The address of the variable, sitting on the stack, is returned. After returning from the function, the next function call can - and will - reuse that space.

Between the function call erroneously returning this address and the call using the value, nothing happens - in your case. Be aware that even this might be different on systems where interrupts may occur, and as well on systems with signals being able to interrupt the normal program run.

The first `printf()` call now uses the stack for its own purpose - maybe it is even the call itself which overwrites the old value. So the second `printf()` call receives the value now written into that memory.

On undefined behaviour, anything may happen.