# why array shows garbage value when only one format specifier used?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

i am trying to print value of an array in C-language.I am using 3 format specifier for only one value of array ,   my problem is that i don't understand that how other two values are coming in my output .

here is my code:

```
int arr[6] = {3,4,42,2,77,8};

 printf("%d %d %d ",arr[2]);

  output :
  42 3 4
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936394/why-the-second-printf-prints-garbage-value

Comment: you have fewer arguments than the format specifier requires so you have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.

In your call of printf

```
printf("%d %d %d ",arr[2]);
```

the arguments are exhausted after the first format specjfjer. So the function call has undefined behaviour and the output can contain any garbage.

You shall write

```
printf( "%d ", arr[2] );
```

or for example

```
printf( "%d %d %d ", arr[2], arr[3], arr[4] );
```

Answer (score 1):

When `printf()` sees three format specifiers, it looks at specific locations, either in stack memory or in CPU registers, depending on the conventions of the compiler, for three arguments.

You provided one, but some data that you have no control over exists in the other two locations, and that's what gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

The other two values are garbage and don't have any meaning. The function printf requires as many arguments as there are format specifiers, so in your case three. Since you only provided one argument (`arr[2]`), the other two specifier 'don't know' what to print - thus gargabe will come out. Make sure to provide the required number of arguments.

If you want to print the array number by number, you will have to use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of printf is.

```
int printf(char*, ...);
```

So, you can have a variable number of arguments, then.

```
printf("%d %d %d ",arr[2]);
```

Is a valid call of the function printf.

However, because you provided no values ​​yourself, then you will get whatever... that in your special case it seems that it printed `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.